# how add checkbox according to while loop and database

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have this code and I have a table in a database. I want to add checkboxes according to the fetched number from the database.

Ex. If the db number is 4 then add 4 checkboxes.

I have css codes to change checkbox to toggle switch my codes work for checkbox without css code but not work when css codes work and when css code is excuted i can't checked or unchecked I think this is a problem with my php code my 
how i can solve this problem to work my query
code is:[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please include code, not images of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you get this error because you have some mistake on line 8, I think you miss array name before square bracket.

The main problem with your checkboxes is that all of them have the same `id`, which must be unique on single page. Another problem is that you place all your checkboxes inside one label - when you click on the `label` then browser try to check checkbox inside of it, which one should it mark as checked? You should place each checkbox inside separated labels.

Small tip: If you place checkbox inside `label`, than you don't need `id` for `label` and `checkbox` - it will make your code cleaner, it will still work as it should and you will avoid duplicated `id`.

Btw.: Using this code all your checkboxes will have the same value - isn't there a next problem?

Comment: The next problem is, for example, the status of checkbox number one in the database is 0 and the status of the check box number 2 is 1, The problem is the loop I created corrected the status of check box number 1 on the all entire check boxes@joint....

Comment: see this comment@jhpratt